# how to echo the data of a table row in a modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[image: i want to do this]what I want to do is that the table( in perfiles.php) is related to the modal, when pressing the edit button in a row, the modal opens with their respective data already loaded from the DB and echo in each input

if you need more details please tell me, do not class it as bad, cause im not the best to clarify my questions and i try

```html
//perfiles.php

    <?php 
    
    include 'api/conexion.php';

    $perfil = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM perfil where usuario = '$_SESSION[usuario]'");
    
    ?>

<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Cuit</th>
      <th>Tipo Persona</th>
      <th class="text-right">Cierre de ejercicio</th>
      <th class="text-right">Acciones</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php while($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($perfil)) { ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo " tr_ ".$reg['id']; ?>">
      <td class="row_factura" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['id']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="row_factura" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['nombre']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="row_factura" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['cuit']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="row_factura" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['tipo_persona']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="row_factura text-right" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['cierre_ejercicio']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="td-actions text-right">
        <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-info" data-original-title="" title="ver/editar perfil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_ajustes_perfil" href="#">
                                <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                            </button>
        <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="" title="ver/editar impuestos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_ajustes_impuestos" href="#">
                                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                            </button>
        <button id="<?php echo $reg['id'] ?>" type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="mod('<?php echo $reg['id']; ?>', 'perfiles');" data-original-title="" title="eliminar perfil">
                                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                            </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
//modal

<div class="modal fade" id="modal_ajustes_perfil" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="blue">
        <i class="material-icons">perm_identity</i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h4 class="card-title">Datos del Perfil -
          <small class="category">Completar   perfil</small>
        </h4>
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Cuit</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Tipo persona</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Cierre del ejercicio</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Dirección</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Telefono</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Im Confused in your question... Do you wanna get all rows for each username from Mysql database? or popup window? what you exactly asking give us screenshot of the error or output.

Comment: i want to pass the data of the row to the modal, only that, but I do not know how to do. (no error)

Comment: when I say that I want to pass each row to the modal I mean that if I choose a row, just pass the data in that row

Comment: Could you please give the screenshots? in Table mark the things you want to achieve in the screenshots? or Give a try with the re written code below i have added.

Comment: yeah, i edit the post, please check it

Comment: So //modal is the popup window? Im getting confuse in your Code! Due to the language.. you want to load the normal page contents into the popup window? but what fields are you wanted to load into the input fields. the language is made the confusions.

Comment: So //modal is the popup window? YES;    you want to load the normal page contents into the popup window? Yes;      but what fields are you wanted to load into the input fields.  all the fields nombre, cuit, cierre_ejercicio, etc

Comment: all of the row i selected of course

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154454/discussion-between-ajmal-praveen-and-agustin-osorio).

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues in Getting all rows for each username from mysql Database? I have re written the code, Kindly replace it.

```
//perfiles.php

    <?php 
    include 'api/conexion.php';
    $perfil = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `perfil` WHERE `usuario` = '$_SESSION[usuario]'");
    ?>

<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Cuit</th>
      <th>Tipo Persona</th>
      <th class="text-right">Cierre de ejercicio</th>
      <th class="text-right">Acciones</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($perfil, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        foreach($row as $reg){
        ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo " tr_ ".$reg['id']; ?>">
      <td class="row_factura" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['id']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="row_factura" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['nombre']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="row_factura" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['cuit']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="row_factura" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['tipo_persona']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="row_factura text-right" data-id="<?php echo $reg['usuario'] ?>">
        <?php echo $reg['cierre_ejercicio']; ?>
      </td>
      <td class="td-actions text-right">
        <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-info" data-original-title="" title="ver/editar perfil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_ajustes_perfil" href="#">
                                <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                            </button>
        <button type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="" title="ver/editar impuestos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_ajustes_impuestos" href="#">
                                <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                            </button>
        <button id="<?php echo $reg['id'] ?>" type="button" rel="tooltip" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="mod('<?php echo $reg['id']; ?>', 'perfiles');" data-original-title="" title="eliminar perfil">
                                <i class="material-icons">close</i>
                            </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is for Modal... You need to provide your Db Structure to Edit the rest of things.. what are the fields to be filled for what with the screenshot

```
//modal
    <?php 
    include 'api/conexion.php';
    $perfil = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `perfil` WHERE `usuario` = '$_SESSION[usuario]'");
    ?>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($perfil, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_ajustes_perfil" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header card-header-icon" data-background-color="blue">
        <i class="material-icons">perm_identity</i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h4 class="card-title">Datos del Perfil -
          <small class="category">Completar   perfil</small>
        </h4>
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $reg['nombre']; ?>" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Cuit</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $reg['cuit']; ?>" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Tipo persona</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $reg['tipo_persona']; ?>" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Cierre del ejercicio</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $reg['cierre_ejercicio']; ?>" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Dirección</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $reg['email']; ?>">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group label-floating">
                <label class="control-label">Telefono</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $reg['telefono']; ?>">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<?php } ?>
```